# Is there a way to color the Sparkline in gtExtras?

Tags: r, gt, gtextras

I am working on a gtExtras table with the following example

```
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(dplyr)

dd <- data.frame(
  where = c("where1", "where2", "where3", "where4"),
  "year_2014" = c(30, 60, 20, 10),
  "year_2022" = c(10, 50, 30, 20)) 

dd |> rowwise() |>
  mutate(change = list(c(year_2014, year_2022))) |>
  gt() |>
  gt_plt_sparkline(change, label = FALSE)
```

[image]

I intend to color the Sparkline (the full Sparkline and not the end, as it in the default) depending on whether there was a decrease "green" or an increase "red".

How do I proceed?

Comment: The colour of the line is hardcoded, it is 1st colour from palette argument, which by default is "black", see https://github.com/jthomasmock/gtExtras/blob/0e814971f5fe944afb5d1e321c49e6590dfffaa3/R/gt_plt_sparkline.R#L174, maybe submit a feature request at GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. I have submitted the feature request.

Comment: @zx8754 you may want to consider doing plots in `gt` directly. Starting in version 0.10.0, sparkline and bar charts can be embedded directly with `cols_nanoplot()`. You can control colors with `nanoplot_options()`.

Comment: @rdelrossi Feel free to submit as an answer below. Hopefully, B.M Njuguna will find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing plots in `gt` directly. Starting in version 0.10.0, sparkline and bar charts can be embedded directly with `cols_nanoplot()`. You can control colors with `nanoplot_options()`.